# IMPORTXML function for Google Sheets fetches some elements but not others

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-parsing, google-sheets

I want to pull upvotes and views data for certain Quora answers. I am trying to do this using Google Spreadsheet's IMPORTXML function. To get Upvotes data this is the code I am using:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-good-online-tutorials-and-books-to-learn-Android-development/answer/Pushpa-Latha-38","//span[@class='count']")
```

For some reason, this is showing #N/A (Imported content is empty) message. When I use same XPath query on XPath Helper plugin for Chrome, I do get the data. Before I execute this, I am also getting total views for this answer using similar code:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-good-online-tutorials-and-books-to-learn-Android-development/answer/Pushpa-Latha-38","//div[@class='CredibilityFact']")
```

This seem to work fine. But not the first one. What's wrong with that one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bot fetching pages for `importXML`  is an anonymous visitor to the site. So it can only get what the site shows to anonymous visitors. By opening the page in a browser where you are not logged in (or in private/incognito window of your browser), you will find that there are  no elements with class `count`: upvotes are not shown.

---

Generally, to see what `importXML` sees, one should open the page in incognito mode and view its *source*. Besides the distinction between anonymous and logged-in visitors, many sites modify the page using JavaScript, which the `importXML` bot does not execute.